# Rails How to Disable Email Validation Unique Check

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my app I am using the devise gem , but what I need now is to allow duplication of email while customer registration.How can I implement it, I tried editing the code in the Customer.meodel fiel but nothing worked.
my customer model code is:

```
validates :firstname, presence: true
validates :lastname, presence: true

validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },uniqueness:  { case_sensitive: false }

validates_format_of :phoneno, :with =>  NUMBER_REGEX, :massage => "Only positive number without spaces are allowed"

has_many :payments
```

How can I avoid this email uniqueness checking in Customer.rb ?

Comment: And when logging in, user inputs email and... your applicaion is confused.

Comment: If you let people sign in with their email address and password, you don't want any duplicate email addresses, or you won't know which user you are dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
uniqueness:  { case_sensitive: false }
```

means it's still validate for uniqueness without case sensitive, pls try change it as

```
uniqueness:  false
```